# How to define query string directly after domain without preceding slash? - ui router

Tags: angular-ui-router

I try to achieve a state, to which I can navigate with `example.com?foo=bar`
I have the following state:

```
$stateProvider 
  .state('state', {
    url: '?foo'
  });
```

The problem is, that it gets interpreted as relative state.

So depending on the current state, I might end up not only at `example.com?foo=bar`, but any other like `example.com/path/to/somewhere?foo=bar`.

One solution would be to define the state with a preceding slash:

```
$stateProvider 
  .state('state', {
    url: '/?foo'
  });
```

But I would like to avoid the route to be `example.com/?foo=bar`, which is kind of ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the ui-router documentation (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing), you can use absolute states using the ^ prefix

Try out:

```
$stateProvider 
  .state('state', {
    url: '^?foo'
  });
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Maybe it only applies to nested states.